# How to exit Assembler back to Applesoft Basic on Apple II GS

Tags: apple2gs

When writing in Applesoft Basic on my Apple II GS, a crashed program occasionally dumps me not at the Applesoft Basic prompt (`]`), but at the assembler prompt instead (`*`). How can I get out of the Assembler and back to Basic (no pun intended)?

Comment: Um, Daniel, I may be wrong, but isn't it called the Apple II GS? [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_IIGS)

Comment: Apple had various ways of rendering the Roman numeral two in stylized ASCII... the boot screen, the case of its various products, etc. // and ][ were both used in place of II.

Comment: Ok. When writing the tag wiki, I saw Apple IIGS, so was wondering...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just type Ctrl-C.

(Or Ctrl-B if you don't care about wiping any Applesoft program in memory. Also, ">" is the Integer Basic prompt. The monitor prompt is "*".)

Comment: 'Doh. You're right. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

Type `3D0G` at the assembler prompt. This will cause the computer to goto/execute the instructions starting at memory address 3D0 Hex/976 decimal, which is the address for the Applesoft Basic interpreter.

Comment: This only works if you have DOS or ProDOS loaded.  Nick Westgate's answer above works without DOS.